# How see the function code in Firefox 25 console?

Tags: javascript, firefox, console

Sorry for my bad english.

In older versions (Firefox 22 or less i think) there was the possibly see the function code, as also in array or literal objects, without the necessity of to click in "[object Array]" or "[object Object]" to see. Was very more simple. I want know if exists some way of resolves this. I tried  in "about:config" and don't found nothing about this.

Comment: `myFunction.toString()` or `myFunction.toSource()`

Comment: Firebug comes to mind...

Comment: `console.dir(your_object)`

Comment: Thanks for the answers! 
`Function.toString` and `Function.toSource` methods i've knew but i forgot them :) Helps a lot as well as `console.dir`.
Firebug i use to some things, but a prefer the Firefox console.